# Getting Arithmetic Exception to handle multiplying by zero

Tags: java, exception, math

For a homework assignment, I have to create a simple program that takes two numbers as arguments, and multiplies them.  If one of the numbers is a zero, the program throws an ArithmeticException

It always seemed to me when I read the documentation however that AritmeticException only handles divide by zero errors and other things that are impossible by math.  However, the assignment wants this built-in handler to do the work, so how do you get it to accept a multiply by zero as an error?

My code so far (which is coded to only handle divide by zero and other "standard" math errors)

```
public class MultTwo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        System.out.println(firstNum*secondNum);
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException a) {
        System.out.println("You're multplying by zero!");
    }

}//end main
}//end MultTwo Class
```

Comment: throw `ArithmeticException` if any value is zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
if (firstNum == 0 || secondNum == 0) {
   throw new ArithmeticException("You're multplying by zero!");
}
```

Though this is not a good practice I guess your teacher wants to show you something with it.

Comment: Basically it.  We then go ahead and make a custom Exception class that does this for us.

Now I see that she's trying to show us how throwing works.

Comment: Yes, so I think the achieves success with this.

Answer (score 3):

As you figured out, that exception won't be thrown automatically in that case, so you need to throw it yourself:

```
if (firstNum == 0 || secondNum == 0) {
    throw new ArithmeticException("Numbers can't be null");
}
//continue with the rest of your code.
```

Notes:

- you don't need to catch `ArithmeticException`
- you should probably catch `NumberFormatException` in case the inputs are not valid integers.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you should throw the exception, not handle it. Something like:

```
int multiply(int firstNum, int secondNum)
{
    if(firstNum == 0 || secondNum == 0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("Multplying by zero!");
    return firstNum * secondNum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The jvm will never throw `ArithmeticException` for multiplying any number with zero, you will have to throw it explicitly.

You can do like this :

```
try {
    int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    if(firstNum == 0 || secondNum == 0){
          throw new ArithmeticException();
    }
    else{
          System.out.println(firstNum*secondNum);
    }
}
catch (ArithmeticException a) {
    System.out.println("You're multplying by zero!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The arithmetic system will never throw an exception for multiplying by zero, since that's entirely valid e.g.

```
double res = 3.141 * 0.0;
```

gives 0.0.

Instead you need to detect a zero, and throw if you have that e.g.

```
if (res == 0.0) {
   throw new ArithmeticException("You have a zero");
}
```

You can check either input for zero. You could check your result for zero instead, since (theoretically) you could only get a zero output if one or both inputs were zero. However Java can't store numbers to a infintesimal precision and two very small inputs could potentially yield zero. e.g.

```
Double.MIN_NORMAL * Double.MIN_NORMAL
```

gives me 0.0

The section above doesn't apply for `Integers`, and so you *could* check your result in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...................

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class T {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


            int firstNum = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
            int secondNum = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

            if (firstNum == 0 || secondNum == 0) {

                throw new ArithmeticException("Numbers can't be zero");
            }

            else{
            System.out.println(firstNum*secondNum);
            }



    }

}
```